Rails multidomain project, it shows only Welcome page, other routes show routing error
I have a project with multiple subdomains for companies. When I access the project in production, it first shows the welcome page of the project, which has a login button that I can use to log in. This page is of the format xxx.domain_name.com.
When I try to start the Rails server using simply rails s,
it only shows the Rails welcome page. When I try to access other paths, for example,
xxx.domain_name.com/profile, it shows
Routing error. No route matches
I have tried many approaches, including editing /etc/hosts to add the domains and subdomains, starting the server with the flag -b:
rails s -p 3000 -b xxx.local.domain_name.dev
and other methods. Still, the server log shows the welcome controller of Rails:
Started GET "/welcome" for 127.0.0.1
when I access localhost:3000, and I get a routing error for other paths. In routes.rb, I have constraints like
constraints subdomain: /^(?!x|y|z)(\w+)/ do 
... 
end

where x, y, z are subdomains, but excluding company subdomains.
The question is: how can I properly deploy the project so that routing works correctly?

Add the relevant configuration- you are asking people to guess at what you have tried

What configuration needs to be posted? By the way, I was able to resolve the domain, and now I can access the domain at the desired address, but it still displays the Rails Welcome Page
